# creating lists of nodes in a list

Tags: 7, users

is there currently a module that allows a user to bookmark a bunch of nodes and name them? E.g. create a bookmark of each movie and name the list, "comedy".

I'm guessing using the [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module would be the best bet but i'm not sure how to store attributes to flags and how to create separate flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the [Flag Page](http://drupal.org/project/flag_page) module which expands on the Flag API, or the [Bookmark](http://drupal.org/project/bookmark) module.

For the Flag API, look at the [Flag Lists](http://drupal.org/project/flag_lists) module which will allow your user to create multiple private lists of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use or perhaps find inspiration in the [Bookmark Organizer module](http://drupal.org/project/bookmarkorganizer). It has the functionality you are describing in your question.

Comment: I looked at that but it's UI is a bit overly complex and not flexible. But thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can bookmark the nodes in Drupal 7 using the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module:

1. Download the flag module and enable it.
2. Create a new flag by visiting admin/structure/flags and then clicking on "Add a new flag" link.

You can create separate the flags by clicking "Add a new flag" link again and giving some other name to the flag.